# Determine object index of a specific string

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am looking the way how to iterate through the following object and determine which index `item-2` (or any other string) belongs too. In this case I would expect index [0] and for the case of `item-2` [1]

The string I am looking to determine the index for, will always exist as the first object index - in the below example `item-1` and `item-2`

```
var products = [
  ["item-1",
  "image1.png",
  "image2.png",
  "image3.png"
  ],
  ["item-2",
  "image1.png",
  "image2.png"
  ]
];
```

Any suggestions how solve this? I was thinking something like a for loop and doing a `indexOf` string check - but not entirely sure how to specifically search the first index or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function FindIndex(InputArray, SearchItem)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < InputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (InputArray[i][0] == SearchItem)
            return i;
    }

    return -1;  // not found
}
```